# Intuition behind intersection multiplicity for plane algebraic curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, taylor-expansion

I am trying to understand what the intuition behind the intersection multiplicity of two plane algebraic curves is/should be. I know that there are different ways to define this value, but the book I am working with right now uses the following: Let $g,f \in k[x,y]$ s.t. $f$ and $g$ have no factor in common. Assume that $f(0,0)=g(0,0)=0$. Denote the associated curves with $F,G$. The intersection multiplicity of $F,G$ at $P=(0,0)$ is the number:

$$ I(P,F\cap G):=\dim_k B  $$

where $B=(k[x,y]/(f,g))/(x,y)^n$ and $n$ is the  number s.t. $(x,y)^N=(x,y)^{N+1}$ for all $N\geq n$. Such a number exists because we know that $k[x,y]/(f,g)$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

So far so good. I know what all of this means and I can work with it i.e. I can compute the dimension for examples. My question is:

> What is the intuition behind this definition? Or in other words: How does one come up with this definition?

Here are my thougths so far: Let's assume $k=\mathbb{C}$ from here on. We can write the Taylor expansion for $f$ and $g$ at $P=(0,0)$ using [multi indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Generalizations_of_Taylor.27s_theorem).

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x,y) &=& f(0,0) + \sum_{\vert\alpha \vert\geq 1}\dfrac{D^\alpha f(0,0)}{\alpha!}x^\alpha\\
g(x,y) &=& g(0,0) + \sum_{\vert\alpha \vert\geq 1}\dfrac{D^\alpha g(0,0)}{\alpha!}x^\alpha
\end{eqnarray}

My intuition now tells me that $I(P,F\cap G)$ should agree with $\vert \alpha \vert$ s.t. $$f(x,y)-g(x,y)=\sum_{\vert \alpha \vert=I(P,F\cap G)}\dfrac{D^\alpha f(0,0)-D^\alpha g(0,0)}{\alpha!}x^\alpha+\text{higher order terms},$$

where of course the $\sum_{\vert \alpha \vert=I(P,F\cap G)}\frac{D^\alpha f(0,0)-D^\alpha g(0,0)}{\alpha!}x^\alpha \neq 0$. The intuition is coming from the geometric picture that the multiplicity at $P$ should somehow measure how "tangent" the two curves are to each other. I computed some examples and for those it is indeed true but I have a hard time proving it in full generality. And maybe it's wrong all together. I would appreciate if somebody could give me a proof or point to one or in general can give me more insight to my question above.

Comment: Have a look at Fulton's book on algebraic curves: (http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf). The basic idea is he writes down a list of properties that intersection multiplicity should satisfy and shows the weird definition does indeed satisfy that list of properties. This is section 3.3, but you might need to read a few things from 3.1 and 3.2. For some reason I have some memory of pictures in this book of intersecting curves and their intersection multiplicity but it could be some other text...

Comment: @hwong557 Thanks a lot for answering! I'm browsing through the text right now and it is indeed very helpful. I would still be interested in further input. Especially in something that would link the algebraic and the analytic picture some more.

Comment: I suggest that you work out a simple example first to see why your definition above using Taylor expansion is too crude. For example, try $f=x^2+y^3, g=y^4$.

Comment: Thanks @Mohan ! I was already expecting that this is way to crude. I will calculate your example tomorrow morning. I still think there has to be some nice geometric/analytic explanation. Something more than: it is the right thing to do s.t. Bezout becomes true.

Comment: You might look at Example 1.2.5 of Fulton's _Intersection Theory_ and the references there. If one of the two curves is sufficiently nice then it seems like there is a satisfying answer.

Comment: The intuition is the following. You perturb your two varieties at a point and intersect themselves, then the intersection number should not change.